# Ruby: Writing to file in subdirectory

Tags: ruby, file

I am trying to write to a file inside a subdirectory. This file is created by the code but, once the file is created, it is empty after the script finishes its execution. What am I doing wrong?

```
# Creating output files
print "Creating output files and filling root menu..."
FileUtils.cd(outdir) do
  file = File.new("directory.xml", "w")
  file.puts "<?php header(\"Content-type: text/xml\"); ?>"
  file.puts "<CiscoIPPhoneMenu>"
  file.puts "<Title>Telefonbuch</Title>"
  file.puts "<Prompt>Dir External</Prompt>"
  letters_used.each do |letter|
    filename = "contacts_" + letter + ".xml"
    FileUtils.touch(filename)
    file.puts "<MenuItem>"
    file.puts "<Name>" + letter.upcase + "</Name>"
    file.puts "<URL>http://" + HOSTNAME + WEBSERV_DIR + "/" + filename + "</URL>"
    file.puts "</MenuItem>"
  end
  file.puts "</CiscoIPPhoneMenu>"
  file.rewind
end
print "Done\n"
```

"directory.xml" should link to each "contacts_letter.xml" file, which is created by the script too, however directory.xml is empty. Why?

Comment: try replacing `file.rewind` with `file.close`

Comment: Yes, I was just writing the same comment... I was unable to recreate the issue though.  You should be closing the file in either case but, if that doesn't fix it please list your OS and ruby version.

Comment: You could also add a file.flush before closing/rewinding the file

Comment: @TheConstructor `close` flushes automatically - http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/IO.html#method-i-close

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Idiomatic Ruby would write to the file using a block:

```
File.new("directory.xml", "w") do |fo|
  fo.puts "<?php header(\"Content-type: text/xml\"); ?>"
  fo.puts "<CiscoIPPhoneMenu>"
  fo.puts "<Title>Telefonbuch</Title>"
  fo.puts "<Prompt>Dir External</Prompt>"
  letters_used.each do |letter|
    filename = "contacts_" + letter + ".xml"
    FileUtils.touch(filename)
    fo.puts "<MenuItem>"
    fo.puts "<Name>" + letter.upcase + "</Name>"
    fo.puts "<URL>http://" + HOSTNAME + WEBSERV_DIR + "/" + filename + "</URL>"
    fo.puts "</MenuItem>"
  end
  fo.puts "</CiscoIPPhoneMenu>"
end
```

This closes the file automatically at the end of the block.

Comment: Yes, the block solution was helpful, then.